# how to retrieve values from database and show it in a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a drop-down field in that I have 2 options(rate high and rate low) when I select rate high it it should display results in descending order or if I select rate low it should display the results in ascending order.I have tried a code that is not working.

my html code is:

```
<select id="ddlViewBy"  onchange="order()">
  <option value="high">Rate(high)</option>
  <option value="low">Rate(low)</option>
</select>
```

my JavaScript code is:

```
function order() { 
  var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if(strUser == 'high')
  {
  <?php
  $post->id="10";
  $mylink = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_biddings WHERE job_id = %d ORDER BY client_bill DESC", $post->id), ARRAY_A);
  if($_GET['bid_id'])
  {
    foreach ( $mylink as $row ) 
    {   
    $id= $row['user_id'];
    $nam=$row["name"];
    $stat=$row['state'];
    $cnty=$row['country'];
    $desc=$row["description"];
    $bid=$row['id'];
    $dat=$row['submission_date'];
    echo '<a href="../../wp-content/themes/businessfinder/profile_register.php?id=$id&view" target="_blank">';
    echo "<div class='mr-btm' style='width:98%'>";
    echo "<h3 style='text-transform:uppercase; line-height:0'><b>$name</b></h3>";
    echo "<p style='color:#808080; text-transform:uppercase;'>$stat,$cnty</p>";
    echo "<p style='color:#808080;'>$desc</p>";
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'>categories : </date>";
    echo "<date style='color:#808080;'>";
    if($row["plumbing"] != '')
    echo $row["plumbing"]; 
    if($row["electrical"] != '') 
    echo $row["electrical"];
    if($row["heating"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["heating"]; 
    if($row["ventilation"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["ventilation"]; 
    if($row["flooring"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["flooring"]; 
    echo ".</date>";

    echo "<table class='btm-cm'><tr><td>";
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'> Id : </date><date style='color:#808080;'>$bid</date> </td> <td style='color:#35cbcp;'>  | </td><td>"; 
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'> submitted on:  </date><date style='color:#808080;'>$dat</date></td></tr></table></div></a>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "nothing found";
  }
}
?>
}
else if(strUser == 'low')
{
<?php
$post->id="10";
$mylink = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_biddings WHERE job_id = %d ORDER BY client_bill ASC", $post->id), ARRAY_A);
  if($_GET['bid_id'])
  {
    foreach ( $mylink as $row ) 
    {   
    $id= $row['user_id'];
    $nam=$row["name"];
    $stat=$row['state'];
    $cnty=$row['country'];
    $desc=$row["description"];
    $bid=$row['id'];
    $dat=$row['submission_date'];
    echo '<a href="../../wp-content/themes/businessfinder/profile_register.php?id=$id&view" target="_blank">';
    echo "<div class='mr-btm' style='width:98%'>";
    echo "<h3 style='text-transform:uppercase; line-height:0'><b>$name</b></h3>";
    echo "<p style='color:#808080; text-transform:uppercase;'>$stat,$cnty</p>";
    echo "<p style='color:#808080;'>$desc</p>";
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'>categories : </date>";
    echo "<date style='color:#808080;'>";
    if($row["plumbing"] != '')
    echo $row["plumbing"]; 
    if($row["electrical"] != '') 
    echo $row["electrical"];
    if($row["heating"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["heating"]; 
    if($row["ventilation"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["ventilation"]; 
    if($row["flooring"] != '')
    echo ",".$row["flooring"]; 
    echo ".</date>";

    echo "<table class='btm-cm'><tr><td>";
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'> Id : </date><date style='color:#808080;'>$bid</date> </td> <td style='color:#35cbcp;'>  | </td><td>"; 
    echo "<date style='color:#35cbc9;'> submitted on:  </date><date style='color:#808080;'>$dat</date></td></tr></table></div></a>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "nothing found";
  }
}
?>
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code you show is PHP and **not** JavaScript ...

Comment: we can write php code inside javascript

Comment: In what environment can we do that? We can use PHP to generate JS code, yes, but there is imo no way to execute PHP code inside JS code without the use of something like AJAX or the like. Even then we just trigger some PHP code and not really include it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the php as being the author of a letter which is then  placed in an in an envelope and *snail mailed*  to the browser. The browser opens it, reads it, and runs the instructions. The author of the letter can't add more content once its been posted.

In other words PHP is executed serverside, javascript is executed clientside

You'll want to look into ajax.

Here is the  [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to get you started

Comment: Technically, he could as well have a JS array variable, which he populates with the array values from PHP before the page runs, then outputs the html with JS. OR he could retrieve the value from the HTML after page load and sort a new array, then output it on change of the dropdown

Comment: @Tyblitz thanks for the suggestion. but I can't understand can you say or give a example clearly. please